# Shortcut for vowels with accents from Spanish using US keyboard layout

Tags: mac, keyboard, language

I write regularly in both Spanish and English, and I have a US keyboard layout. I'm aware that one of the key combinations for generating vowels with accents (á, é, í, ó, ú) is: Opt. + e + the desired vowel. However, this is somewhat cumbersome when trying to type fast in Spanish. Now my question: Is it possible to create a shortcut for generating the vowels with accents by only typing one key before the vowel like in a Spanish layout, but keeping the US layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to make the kind of custom layout you want with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it imply that the is no way to do it natively?

Comment: Try the Input source called US International PC.